# Android ImageView will not match_parent width

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have an ImageView that is 1x20px. The image is a .9.png. I am trying to use match_parent but when I run the app on my device, it is not stretched to fill the width of the screen. Here's the code in the XML for the ImageView

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/dividerBar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/ic_bar" 
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

Any ideas on how I can get the ImageView to cover the entire width of the screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a 9 patch it needs to be set as the background attribute of the imageview for it to scale properly. Right now it's trying to scale the image as it would any other image using the scaleType tag that you provided.

Try setting

```
android:background="@drawable/ic_bar"
```

and remove the src attribute

Additionally, if you are using the imageView only to display the 9-patch you can switch to using a regular View instead of the ImageView. As long as you set the background attribute you will be good to go.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you for your quick and helpful response.